# How to output logs of different levels to stdout based on a cmd line parameter?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I use slf4j 1.7.2 with logback 1.0.7. I want to be able to supply a command line parameter to my Java application that sets the level of messages logged to stdout. For example, `-logLevel trace` should result in all messages logged but `-logLevel warning` only in warnings and errors. The logs should come from all loggers in the application (= the root logger).

Currently I have a `ConsoleAppender` for `System.out` that ensures, by means of `TresholdFilter`,  that only `info` `warning` and `error` messages are printed out to stdout. The root logger references it. I don't know how to programatically change the filtered levels for this appender, which I need to base the logged levels on a command line parameter.

While the levels logged to stdout should be influenced, I still want for the root logger to log all levels, as they are sent to other appenders, e.g. `diagnostics.txt` file that should have all the levels all the time.

Cheers!
Konrad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logback's configuration file allows the use of variables. You can define a System property (-D parameter to the JVM), and the use that value in the configuration file. The syntax is:

```
${VARIABLE_NAME}
```

You should be able to define a variable, say -DSYSOUT_LOG_LEVEL=ERROR
Then, in your logback.xml file, instead of setting a specific level for the filter, you can use ${SYSOUT_LOG_LEVEL}, e.g.

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
  <level>${SYSOUT_LOG_LEVEL}</level>
</filter>
```

Comment: Works, thanks! [Logback doc mentioning this](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingProps).